# Why is this sqlite database column not being created?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, blob

I am trying to add a new column(image) to my sq lite database however whenever I try to add values to the column(image) it crashes and says there is no such column. It seems like its not creating the column but I cannot see why.

Here is a print out of the error and the rest of my code.

> StackTrace

```
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: image (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, task, date, image FROM mainToDo
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at com.gnumbu.errolgreen.importedapplication.DBAdapter.getAllRows(DBAdapter.java:96)
        at com.gnumbu.errolgreen.importedapplication.PeekFragment.populateListView(PeekFragment.java:135)
        at com.gnumbu.errolgreen.importedapplication.PeekFragment.onActivityCreated(PeekFragment.java:99)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1794)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handle
```

> DBAdapter.java

public class DBAdapter {

```
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TASK, KEY_DATE, KEY_IMAGE};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
public static final int COL_DATE = 2;
public static final int COL_IMAGE = 3;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbToDo";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainToDo";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TASK + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT"
        + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB"
        + ");";


private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String task, String date, byte[] image ) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);


    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date, byte[] image) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    newValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

}

> PeekFragment.java

```
public class PeekFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    //Delcare Public Variables !
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    DBAdapter myDB;
    EditText etTasks;
    ImageView img;
    ByteArrayBuffer baf ;
    ImageView dbimage ;




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout, container, false);
        Button a = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addTask);
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        a.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.addTask:

                today.setToNow();
                String timestamp = today.format("%Y-%-m-%d %H:%M:%S");

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etTasks.getText().toString())) {

                    dbimage.buildDrawingCache();//Draws image to bitmap
                    Bitmap bmap = dbimage.getDrawingCache();

                    myDB.insertRow(etTasks.getText().toString(), timestamp, getBytes(bmap));

                }
                break;
            case R.id.deleteButton:
                myDB.deleteAll();
                break;
        }
        populateListView();
    }



    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        etTasks = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextTask);
        dbimage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dbImageUpload);
        openDB();
       // new Task_like_flag().execute();
       // img =(ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewpicture);
        populateListView();
        listViewItemClick();
        listViewItemLongClick();

        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_TASK, DBAdapter.KEY_IMAGE};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.idView, R.id.resourceView, R.id.imageViewpicture};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.tobedeletedd_view, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0) {
        };
        ListView myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    }

    /**
     * public void onClick_AddTask(View v) {
     * today.setToNow();
     * String timestamp = today.format("%Y-%-m-%d %H:%M:%S");
     * <p/>
     * if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etTasks.getText().toString())) {
     * myDB.insertRow(etTasks.getText().toString(), timestamp);
     * <p/>
     * }
     * populateListView();
     * }
     */

    private void openDB() {
        myDB = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        myDB.open();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_TASK, DBAdapter.KEY_IMAGE};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.idView, R.id.resourceView, R.id.imageViewpicture};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.tobedeletedd_view, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0) {
        };
        ListView myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    }

    private void updateTask(long id) {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.getRow(id);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String task = etTasks.getText().toString();
            today.setToNow();
            String date = today.format("%Y-%-m-%d %H:%M:%S");

            dbimage.buildDrawingCache();//Draws image to bitmap
            Bitmap bmap = dbimage.getDrawingCache();

            myDB.updateRow(id, task, date,getBytes(bmap));
        }

        cursor.close();
    }

    private void listViewItemClick() {
        ListView myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                updateTask(id);
                populateListView();
            }
        });
    }




    private void listViewItemLongClick() {
        ListView myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                myDB.deleteRow(id);
                populateListView();

                return false;
            }
        });

    }
/**
    public Bitmap convertBlobToBitmap(byte[] blobByteArray) {
        Bitmap tempBitmap=null;
        if(blobByteArray!=null)
            tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blobByteArray, 0, blobByteArray.length);
        return tempBitmap;
    }
    public class Task_like_flag extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        JSONObject object_feed;
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/cWdWl6L.png");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  //http://example.com/image.jpg
            //open the connection
            URLConnection ucon = null;
            try {
                ucon = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //buffer the download
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = ucon.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,128);
            baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);
            //get the bytes one by one
            int current = 0;
            try {
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            today.setToNow();
            String timestamp = today.format("%Y-%-m-%d %H:%M:%S");
            String voteText = "Test";
            myDB.insertRow(etTasks.getText().toString(), timestamp, baf.toByteArray(), voteText);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            byte[] imageByteArray;
            Bitmap theImage = null;
            try{
                Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchAllNotes();
               // startManagingCursor(myDB);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                    do {
                        imageByteArray   =  cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_IMAGE));
                        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
                        theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.v("Excep", ""+e);
            }
            img.setImageBitmap(theImage);
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
*/


    // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }

}
```

Comment: There needs to be a semi-colon after "TEXT" in your create table.  It should have crashed in error when creating the database.  You need to delete the app and reinstall to rebuild the database (once it's released you need to update the database version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantely what you have done is creating the database then you altered the sql creation statement and that will not upgrade your database you have to increment the database version number and drop the schema on the `onUpgrade()` callback then recreate the database. This how it works.

You just need to increment `DATABASE_VERSION` to 2

and yet another error is that you forgot a comma in your SQL creation statement. It should be

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TASK + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB"
        + ");";
```